# How to update HP ProBook 4520s BIOS in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04

I have recently installed ubuntu 12.0 on my laptop. This was done due to infected BIOS while i was using windows 7 ultimate. It got currupted and i had to remove/replace it by ubuntu. Now I want to Flash/update BIOS.

How can I update BIOS hp ProBook 4520s in ubuntu  environment?

Answer (score 1):

1- Go to http://welcome.hp.com/country/us/en/support.html and find your product. The BIOS can be downloaded as an exe file, such as sp40578.exe.

2- Install the package 'cabextract'

3- Type '`cabextract <filename> --filter ISO/rom.iso`' 
and you'll get a directory 'ISO' with a file rom.iso

4- Burn the iso to a CD.

5- Reboot the pc from this CD and follow instructions.